# My website keeps getting squezed and messed when rezied

Tags: html, css, resize

Whenever i Resize my website it keeps getting messed up, and I have tried everything to fix it but i cant figure it out. I tried bootstrap, but didn't quit understand the meaning of it. I am new so advice is appreciated and Thanks for helping

Regard Hussein M.

```css
body {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-repeat: round;
    background-image: url(Gaming.jpg);
    background-position:  -430px -100px;
}


h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;   
}


ul {
    
}

table {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

body { 
    min-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
        margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: medium;   
}

#menu1 {
   float: left;
   padding-left: 25px;
   
}

#menu2 {
   float: right;
   padding-right: 50px;
}

.nav {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: inherit;
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
    padding: 9px 0px 50px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    
}

.nav ul,li,a{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(22, 239, 239);  
}



 .main {
     position: absolute;
     top: 150px;
     left: 5px;
}
    

.h1z1 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 1 auto;
  padding: 0px ;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
}

.h1z1-img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block; 
}

.h1z1-description {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: -25px;
 top: px;
}


.Buy {
 text-decoration: underline;
 margin-left: -8px;
}

.H1Z1head {
  margin: -10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
    
 .go  {
  color:aqua;
  position: fixed;
  top: 190px; 
  left: 380px;
}

 .go  {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 

    <head>  
 <!--Start of Zendesk Chat Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?4aNAebvVIseGLS8uJOO3z9Bsrlfecjl7";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
<!--End of Zendesk Chat Script-->
        
        <title>Gaming Library</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="Stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    
<body>
    <div class="nav"> 
    <ul id="menu1">
        <li><a href="file:///Users/mac/Desktop/index.html">Homes</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.gaminglib.com/pages/about-us">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="a">Affliates</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.paypal.com/signin?country.x=DK">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
        
    <ul id="menu2">
        <li><a href=""http://www.gaminglib.com/"">Old web</a></li>
        <li><a href="a">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="a">Login</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="http://www.gaminglib.com/pages/contact-us-1">Contact Support</a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>
    
   
    
    <div class="go">
    <h1><a href="http://www2.ea.com/featured">Go to feautered games</a></h1>
    </div> 
 
    <!-- Næste side 
  <div class="h1z1">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <h2 class="H1Z1head">H1Z1</h2>
        </ul>
      <img class="h1z1-img" src="KOTK.jpg" width="250" height="180">
    </div>
    <div class="h1z1-description">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>H1Z1: King of the Kill is a fast-paced shooter in which players compete in large-scale chaotic PvP spectacles of skill, wit and a little luck, where everyone must fight to the death to stand alone at the top of the podium.</p>
            <h3 class="Buy"><a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/433850/?l=danish">Buy Now only $20.99 </a></h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason my picture wont appear on snippet..

Comment: Picture does not appear for two reasons, stackoverflow does not allow CORS requests (cross domain origin) and also because the URL is using the root path. So it is trying to resolve at `somecodesnippethostingsite.com/KOTK.jpg` which will return a 404 not found because `somecodesnippethostingsite.com` is not hosting your image.

Comment: menu1 and menu2 are using different alignments, if you were to change that both to  "left" and then change margin-bottom to just margin and say give it a random value of 5.

Comment: i suggest you to watch some bootstrap tutorials

Comment: Hey Gugg, can you write it and show me an example, because should i also then change padding? and should i then give it a position to move it?

Comment: Add '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' in between your '<head>' tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how to get your content responsive with Bootstrap, that you didn't understand. https://jsfiddle.net/qaxhxcb3/1/ (Here u can resize and such)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: green !important;
}

section h1 {
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gaming Library</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Homes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Affliates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- First section -->
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 green">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 red">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 blue">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Second section -->
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 pink">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

As can you see, you put your content inside the class "container", then "row" after than u choose how you will display your content with the grid system. The Bootstrap grid system allows up to 12 columns across the page.

and the grid system has four classes:

- xs (for phones)
- sm (for tablets)
- md (for desktops)
- lg (for larger desktops)

and there is also different columns that decide how it will be displayed on the screen. In the example i got three **col-sm-4** and it must always add up to 12 for each row class. In the second section i created there is col-sm-12, and that fill up the whole grid. Hope this helps a litte bit.

But, i suggest you read some Bootstrap tutorials from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp) to get a hang of it.